# WebView detect when website has loaded successfully

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

how can i detect when a WebView website has loaded successfully with **NO** errors. I tried `onPageFinished` but it still get called when internet connection fails. I want to make my views visible again when the website has loaded successfully with no errors (and no "Website not available")

This is what I am using currently that even calls when the request had an error (e.g. no internet etc.)

```kotlin
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)

    view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    rootView.loadingSpinner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this: Use this (deprecated but still functional) api. Will be called for the main url you are loading, not every web resource like the newer version.  This should take care of both no internet connection and http error responses.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String) {
//hide it, etc...
              // println("ON receive error:  $errorCode  $description  $failingUrl")
}
```

Comment: I **need to know** when there's **no error**. I don't need to know if there's an error. I just need a function where i can be sure that the request was successful

Comment: this is the function. you put a flag here that an error has occurred and do whatever you need in the page finished

Comment: Is this function called before onPageFinished?

Comment: No need to use the deprecated one. The normal one works fine

Comment: How can i detect if it failed specifically because of bad internet connection?